# System.Uri.AbsoluteURI charset encoding

Tags: c#, .net, browser, url-encoding

I use `System.Uri` class to generate an URL for an HTML link. The problem is that it's encode special characters in UTF8 and my browser don't recognize them.

**Sample code** :

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"\\computer\Temp\Réunion.txt");
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
```

**Output** :

*file://computer/Temp/R%C3%A9union.txt*

**Expected** :

*file://computer/Temp/R%E9union.txt*

How can I choose the encoding used by `System.Uri.AbsoluteURI` method ?
Does it exists any alternative solution to convert any path to valid URL ?

Comment: I suspect you've asked something different from what you are actually trying to achieve "convert any path to valid URL" - post already shows how to construct *valid url*, but for some reason it does not work for you... Note that rules for URI and file paths are different (try names with spaces and `+`) - you likely  be better off using "http://" urls and proxying access to files on other computers. Or just construct strings you like by hand to satisfy quirks of browser you use.